# Open book from command line

Tags: macos, books

I can open books on the command line using:

```
/Applications/Books.app/Contents/MacOS/Books
```

but how do I open a specific book if I have the path to it?

Comment: The command is `open path/to/book.epub`. From `man open`: "The open command opens a file (or a directory or URL), just as if you had double-clicked the file's icon. If no application name is specified, the default application as determined via LaunchServices is used to open the specified files."